# What's the source for "The Minhag of Yisroel is Torah"?

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag

B"H

There's a common expression that's quoted often in many different mefarshim of all kinds, and mentioned by many that even things the people of Yisroel accept upon themselves, that's not halacha, is still "Torah".

What is the original source for this statement?

There's a Tosafos in Menachos 20b ד"ה נפסל that touches on this concept, but there it says "the Minhag of our fathers is Torah", and not just a "Minhag" in general.

Comment: https://www.orharambam.com/post/%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%92-%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C-%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90

Comment: Note the phrase (like many idioms) may have meant something different in its original context than in later idiomatic usage, so don't interpret an early source as early support for a later usage's meaning.

Comment: @Avrah " הרמב"ן כתב בחידושיו (פסחים ז ע"ב): "ומנהג ישראל תורה היא". וכידוע, המכשף הכסיל והנחיתי הזה היה מראשוני העבדים הנרצעים למינים האשכנזים... והוא כנראה נמנע מלומר מנהג "אבותינו" כדי שלא יטעו לחשוב שמדובר במנהגי ספרד ח"ו, לפיכך הוא שינה למנהג "ישראל" כדי לכלול את אדוניו המינים" lol, I've never heard that claim made in regards to any other statement. It's very possible there's something, of an implication of something, that the Rambam based this off.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!